# Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

Tags: apache-zookeeper

i configured 3 servers in zookeeper 
this is zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/Alternant/zookeeper/zk1Data
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=10.111.210.19:2888:3888
```

i get this exception when i try to connnect

```
 2020-01-31 14:33:51,041 [myid:localhost:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@959] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50274, server: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181
```

2020-01-31 14:33:51,042 [myid:localhost:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1240] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

Comment: I had this issue today. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700307/7641839) have helped to solve this issue.